# I want to hide the product description and review tabs but

Tags: attribute-set

I have just short product descriptions (jewelry shop) and i think it is best to ad that to the short description so this also shows when people share through FB, Twitter etc.

I think these share options use the short description... correct?

If that is true i do not have any need to show description and neither the review tab

To remove this i thought i had to got to : Cataglogue > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets

Than select default (the only set i have)

Than drag and drop the description from Group to Non assigned attributes

But...

I get the message that i can not do this because it is a system attribute

How can i enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cant since that is a System attribute. You might want to code your way out of this issue, but it cant be fixed from the admin panel.